# VC++ sqlite Compile issues

Tags: sqlite, visual-c++, system

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional

I am trying to create a program that, among other things, uses sqlite to manage a roster of students. I had everything up and running until I tried to start adding UI windows. The UI windows needs to use the System namespace, which requires using /clr. However, the sqlite file is in C and needs to be compiled as /TP. but when I do this, a whole slew of errors pop up.

How can I get the System namespace to run on my project while still using the sqlite library?

Answer (score 1):

Download the DLL version of sqlite, and try to call it from a mixed-mode project.

You may need to create an extra unmanaged DLL like this:

> [your app: C++/CLI mixed-mode app] ---[unmanaged DLL] ---[original sqlite DLL]